# Vuejs: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, frontend

I am trying to create a form with which I can input and update values in a database, but I always get the warning and have no idea how to get rid of it. I have an array that contains objects with id values, for example:

```
data = [{id_a: 2, id_b: 3},{id_a: 5, id_b: 10}, ...]
```

In the template of the relevant component, I am looping over this array, and create a row in a table for each object:

```
<template>
<div>
<table>
<tr
    v-for="(dataset, i) in data"
    :key="i"
    >
    <td>{{ a_selection[dataset.id_a] }}</td>
    <td>{{ b_selection[dataset.id_b] }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</template>
```

since I don't want to display the id values but rather the names which are associated with them, I am getting the names from two objects, here called a_selection and b_selection.

I fetch these objects in the script part from the server during the created hook like so:

```
<script>
import axios
export default {
    created() {
        axios.get(http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_a/").then(response => (this.a_selection= response.data));
        axios.get(http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_b/").then(response => (this.b_selection= response.data));
    },
    data() {
        return {
            a_selection: null,
            b_selection: null,
            data: [{id_a: 2, id_b: 3},{id_a: 5, id_b: 10}]
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

when I try to draw this, I get vue warnings:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null"
```

and type errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
```

For some reason doing it like this trows me a few of these errors, but in the end, correctly displays the wanted table.
Can anybody help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: You get the error "Cannot read property 'x' of null", because `a_selection` and `b_selection` are null, and in your template you are trying to access them with an `x` that is either `dataset.id_a` or `dataset.id_b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the first time it is trying to render `a_selection[2]` that still does not exist

- add new data called `loading` and you can set it to false first
- in the `created()` function before sending any request you can set loading to true `this.loading = true`
- and once you successfully fetch all data from the backend you can set loading back to false again
- and you can use `v-if` to load a loader when it is loading set to true and use `v-else` to render your table when your data is loaded.
- You can use any other data like this (loaded, fetched, ...) to be able to use `v-if` and `v-else` to render your data correctly.

Comment: How would you go about checking if all the data has been loaded? I am fairly new to js and not quite familiar with the asynchronous nature of these calls. The only way I can think of is chaining the server calls together, which would (as far as I understand it...) defeat the purpose of asynchronous calls.